# nanoc: problems testing a compile rule by item name or identifier

Tags: ruby, nanoc

I use the following tests in a nanoc rule for compiling various kinds of content (including partials) in multiple directories by matching them with their identically-named layouts.

Now I've added index files to each content dir, but these need the default layout. This obviously works fine if I add an item named 'index:' to the metadata in the 'index.md' files…

```
---
title: 'This page title'
index: 'y'
---
```

…but checking for `if @item[:index]` seems a bit clunky, so I've been trying (well, hacking around) to find a way to omit 'index:' from the metadata and test by nanoc rep name or identifier - see the commented-out `if` statements in the code below:

```
layouts = ['layoutone','layouttwo','layoutetc']

layouts.each  do |dir|
  compile "/#{dir}/*" do
    # if item.identifier == "/#{dir}/index/"
    # if item.identifier =~ %r{/\w/index/}
    # if @item.rep_named(:index)
    if @item[:index]
     filter :kramdown
      layout "default"
    elsif @item[:inc]
      filter :erb
      filter :kramdown
      layout "#{dir}"
    else
      filter :kramdown
      layout "#{dir}"
    end
  end
end
```

What's wrong with the syntax/logic in my commented-out lines?

### Edit:

I was missing the blindingly obvious here: simply add `/content/dir_name.md` at the same level as `/content/dir_name/*` to create `/dir_name/index.html` and `/dir_name/*.html`, and apply rules to those `/content/dir_name.md` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you change `nanoc.yaml` after `nanoc create-site`? Because I recall that by default, identifiers in `nanoc` don't contain the last `index` part of source file name.

Say, file `content/dirA/index.markdown` will have identifier `/dirA/` or something, and compile to `content/dirA/index.html`. This may be the reason why your `index` regex didn't hit.

Yes, a little tricky, but nanoc is great.

#### update

I found a way to tell the content filename: `item.raw_filename`.

[This document](http://nanoc.ws/docs/api/Nanoc/Item.html#raw_filename-instance_method) says it is only for binary files, while it also work on text files in my experiment.

```
# in compile block of Rules
item.identifier
# => "/aaa/"
item.raw_filename
# => "content/aaa.markdown"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm making sure my /dirname/index.md files are written to /dirname/index.html in my loop. My problem is understanding how to identify index files by the word 'index' in their content name, for the dirs I'm looping through... and yes, nanoc is great!

Comment: @DaveEveritt Ahh I found a (less document supported) way to tell `content/dirname/index.md`. See the update part.

Comment: Thanks for the extra research, but from my attempts (in the commented out lines) it seems `item.identifier` can't take a statement with interpolated variables: `if item.identifier == "/#{dir}/index/"` and this is what I need. BUT I'll try `raw_filename`, report back and 'accept' if it works :-)

Comment: This is the correct answer. "index" is magic in nanoc, much like it's magic in web servers. The identifier for `/foo/index.md` is `/foo/`. `item.identifier` *never* has `/index/` at the end of it.

Comment: I know about the index magic, but your comment made me realise I've been a fool. I could simply add `/content/dir_name.md` at the same level as `/content/dir_name/*` to create `/dir_name/index.html` and `/dir_name/*.html`. D'oh.